# Following an MVC paradigm, how should I effectively have UIViews in a cell that are optionally shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that has a large thumbnail thumbnail in each cell along with a title. The cell may be showing a video, an image, a gallery of photos, or a drawing.

Depending on which of these content types the cell is displaying, the thumbnail will have a small icon on top to make it clear what kind of content is being shown in the cell. So for example if the cell was showing a video, it would have the thumbnail with maybe the triangle play icon on top to show that it's a video. A drawing may have a pencil.

I want to do this in a way that is organized and follows MVC, because I'm trying to learn to keep my code organized and maintainable.

My first thought was to have a `UITableViewCell` subclass for every content type, but that seems like a lot of different classes to maintain when the only thing that changes is a small icon on top.

My next thought was to have a `type` instance variable on the class denoting what it is showing, and then show the icon corresponding to the type. But in this case, isn't the cell a `view` (the V) in MVC, and is the view supposed to handle the *logic* in displaying it as well?

Is there something better yet?

And lastly, how does this work in conjunction with Interface Builder? If it's the latter solution, do I add them all in IB as hidden, then unhide them programmatically depending on the type?

Comment: There are 2 options that I use in this case: either make multiple cell subclasses to handle the different options but if there really isn't much different about the cells the you can use an enumeration (NS_ENUM) to denote the different types of cells and have your controller set the type in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: The controller is responsible for telling the view how to lay itself out. The type determines how the view lays itself out, so it is okay for the controller to tell the view its type. The view will the set the appropriate icon based on the type.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should only display content make as less decision as possible. The best solution would be creating separate cells for each type. This is very solid architecture and it would be esker do changes and add new functionality.

1. Create separate Model for every item (Photo, Video, Drawing)
2. Create a MediaItemCell that will be base class for every itemCells (photo, viode etc).
   Add basic functions that every MediaItem should have
3. Create a separate cell for each type. (PhotoCell, VideoCell, DrawingCell)
   Implement type specific functionality
4. Create 4 difference cells in StoryBoard or Xib file and set correct layout and cellIds

To achieve best performance you should reuse UItableViewCell and avoid changing its layout and modifying cells subview (don't add or remove subviews). That's why it's bad idea to have 1 cell that will show all your objects.

Your viewController would have a collections of items it needs to show. An array of items
[Image, Video, Drawing, Image, ...]
It would be even better to create a separate class that would hold those items and methods to works with those items.
This way you would hide implementation details.
I would call it MediaItemsViewModel - it would hold all items it heeds to show, simple wrapper of array
You can read more [Clean table view code](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html) on objc.io

In the CellForRowAtIndexPath, you would get an Object, and dependent on it's type return corresponding cell for it

Here is code in Swift. You can do similar it Objective-C, also you can do dynamic dispatch on the object type in Objective-C

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  enum Cells: String {
    case Photo = "Photo"
    case Video = "Video"
    case Drawing  = "Drawing"
  }

  let object = objects[indexPath.row]

  switch object {
  case let image as Image:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImgeCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell
    cell.image = image
  case let image as Video:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VideoCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as VIdeoCell
    cell.video = video

  return cell
}
```

Objective-C code.
Very similar to previous code in Swift.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSDictionary *objectCells = @{@"Video": @"VideoCell",
                                @"Image": @"ImageCell",
                                @"Drawing": @"DrawingCell"};
  id<MediaItem>object = objects[indexPath.row];
  NSString *cellID = objectCells[object.type];
  MediaItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
  // MediaItemTableViewCell class that takes MediaItem
  // Every class has it's own implementation to correctly show media item
  cell.object = object


  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Performance-wise is there any issue with having multiple subclasses for cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Wouldn't it make it difficult to reuse cells if there's such a divide in classes used for them?

Comment: No, there no performance problem. You have 3 cells with it's own identifiers. When you ask for PhotoCell, you get photocell (it there is not used one, framework will return it to you and you will reuse it).
It the same as having 1 cell type but int this case you have more things in cache, and it's fine. But if you would have 1 cell for everything - you would need to update your subview - this would case layoutSubiew, and it's expensive

Comment: Also it's bad architecture. Do it SOLID, and Single responsible. You cell should know about 1 thing, not about all.